# How to pass state with React Router?

Tags: reactjs

I'm fetching data of list of champions from JSON file, and am trying to make a link to view each champ and am not sure how to pass img property in the link from react-router.

I tried using `state: champion.img` but it's not giving anything. Any ideas how can I pass the image value?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
class PersonList extends Component {
    state = {
        persons: [],
        name:"",
           champs: [], 
           isLoaded: false,
        Aatrox:''
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/blcps'
        })
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({ persons: res.data[1]})


            console.log(res.data[0].name);
            console.log('ldldl');


             const champions = res.data.map((champion) => {
            console.log(champion.name)
            console.log(this.state.champs.name)
            return <div classname="container-fluid">
            <div classname="row">
            <p>ldldl</p>

              <h2 className="card-title">{champion.name}</h2>   </div> 

               <img src={champion.img} /> 

               <Link to={{ pathname:`/champions/${champion.name}`,// undefined  state: {champion.img} }} > {champion.name}  </Link>
</div> 


   })


          this.setState({ champs: champions, isLoaded: true });



        })


    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
               {this.state.isLoaded ? <div>{this.state.champs}</div> : <div>.</div>}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default PersonList;
```

Comment: try to console.log(champion.img) 
check the output, whether its undefined or not

Comment: its not im actually getting the images

Comment: just dont know how to pass that to different component

Answer (score 0):

when you `console.log(champion.img)`, do you get a full url ? if not you have to place the complete url of the file not just filename for it to work. How you do this depends on what was returned from the server.

Comment: im getting a ful url to the image link

Comment: you should provide a variable name for `champion.img` in state. Like this `state: {img: champion.img}` then retrieve the value using `var img = this.props.location.state.img` or you pass the full champion as state `<Link to={{ pathname:'/champions/${champion}', state: {champion} }} > {champion.name}  </Link>` then retrieve using `var img = this.props.location.state.champion.img`

Comment: or you could set a variable as `champion.img` and pass it instead of `champion.img` in the state.

Comment: like this? 
 <Link to={{ pathname:`/champions/${champ.id}`, state: { img: champ.img} }} >

Comment: then in other component var img = this.props.location.state.img     img src={img}

Comment: Exactly, if it helped you, please tick answered.